# Ошибка «file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect» хотя папка прописана?

Tags: php, nginx

Debian+Nginx+PHP-fpm.

Приветствую. такой конфиг в nginx:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/tmp:/var/www/site:/var/www/content";
```

Но на сайте:

```
Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/var/www/content/bla-bla/bla.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/tmp:/var/www/site:/var/www/content)
```

Хотя вроде доступ к файлу всё равно получен, ибо ничего не упало.

Comment: не фигурируют ли там символические ссылки? [все символические ссылки будут раскрыты, так что с их помощью не удастся обойти это ограничение](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: Конкретно по всем папкам не знаю, но та на которую ссылаюсь имеет прямой путь.

Comment: `$ readlink -f /var/www/content/bla-bla/bla.php` возвращает именно `/var/www/content/bla-bla/bla.php`?